# Why does my Jupyter Notebook file display no contents when opened in Github or JupyterLite?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, version-control, repository

I'm very new to coding. I created an .ipynb file for a learning mod using VScode, which has its own version control. When I try to upload the Notebook to Github or JupyterLite, it shows up as a blank notebook.

[image: Blank Notebook]

Is there is a solution, I would love to know. I'm stumped.

The image below shows the notebook that displays locally in VScode.

[image: VsCode NB]

When trying to upload, whether I drag & drop or browse explorer, the notebook is not readable. The file itself is in a `.vscode` repository which has local version control.

immediately after typing the the last line, I saved a copy of the code to a folder outside of that repository and it shows up on both sites mentioned above just fine. Is there a reason for this? It would be pretty nice to just be able to upload this to GitHub without the extra step.

Comment: I use Git with Github. Then I commit and push the changes, then they show up in GitHub. What is a `.vscode` repository? Could you point to some resource on how you should be using it. Finally, this won't help because you are obviously doing something wrong, but you'd have a better experience thinking of GitHub as a preview. [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) is the Jupyter offering for viewing and sharing notebooks, especially with non-coders. It has many more features so that it renders things better than GitHub. You just point the form at the site at your notebook and you'll get a link ....

Comment: <continued> you can use to share the 'static' view of your notebook with others. If you study a few of the URLs, you'll realize there is a pattern based on the GitHub URL and you can skip putting it in the form and just adapt the URL to point nbviewer at it. I put the word 'static' in quotes because a lot of active things with javascript underlying them, such as plotly plots or pre-generated animations with controller widgets will remain active in the nbviewer rendering, not in GitHub. Example: https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/Plotly3d-scatter-plots.ipynb